# Wordpress 'Our Team' Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woothemes

I currently have the 'Our Team' plugin installed to display team members.

At the moment, the staff description (that appears in the WISYWIG editor area), is pulled through onto the team page along with all the other staff details.

As there is quite a bit of text for each, i would like to have it so that there is just a 'Read about me' link, and the description text appears in a lightbox instead.

I already have a Lightbox plugin in use on the website (WP Lightbox 2), but just need to know how i can change the 'Our Team' template file so that it displays the link rather than the whole block of text.

Below is the 'woothemes-our-team-template.php' file:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

if ( ! function_exists( 'woothemes_get_our_team' ) ) {
/**
* Wrapper function to get the team members from the Woothemes_Our_Team class.
* @param  string/array $args  Arguments.
* @since  1.0.0
* @return array/boolean       Array if true, boolean if false.
*/
function woothemes_get_our_team ( $args = '' ) {
global $woothemes_our_team;
return $woothemes_our_team->get_our_team( $args );
} // End woothemes_get_our_team()
}

/**
* Enable the usage of do_action( 'woothemes_our_team' ) to display team members within a theme/plugin.
*
* @since  1.0.0
*/
add_action( 'woothemes_our_team', 'woothemes_our_team' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'woothemes_our_team' ) ) {
/**
* Display or return HTML-formatted team members.
* @param  string/array $args  Arguments.
* @since  1.0.0
* @return string
*/
function woothemes_our_team ( $args = '' ) {
global $post, $more;

$defaults = apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_default_args', array(
    'limit'                     => 12,
    'per_row'                   => null,
    'orderby'                   => 'menu_order',
    'order'                     => 'DESC',
    'id'                        => 0,
    'slug'                      => null,
    'display_author'            => true,
    'display_additional'        => true,
    'display_avatar'            => true,
    'display_url'               => true,
    'display_twitter'           => true,
    'display_author_archive'    => true,
    'display_role'              => true,
    'contact_email'             => true,
    'tel'                       => true,
    'effect'                    => 'fade', // Options: 'fade', 'none'
    'pagination'                => false,
    'echo'                      => true,
    'size'                      => 250,
    'title'                     => '',
    'before'                    => '<div class="widget widget_woothemes_our_team">',
    'after'                     => '</div>',
    'before_title'              => '<h2>',
    'after_title'               => '</h2>',
    'category'                  => 0
) );

$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

// Allow child themes/plugins to filter here.
$args = apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_args', $args );
$html = '';

do_action( 'woothemes_our_team_before', $args );

    // The Query.
    $query = woothemes_get_our_team( $args );

    // The Display.
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $query ) && is_array( $query ) && count( $query ) > 0 ) {

        $class = '';

        if ( is_numeric( $args['per_row'] ) ) {
            $class .= ' columns-' . intval( $args['per_row'] );
        }

        if ( 'none' != $args['effect'] ) {
            $class .= ' effect-' . $args['effect'];
        }

        $html .= $args['before'] . "\n";
        if ( '' != $args['title'] ) {
            $html .= html_entity_decode( $args['before_title'] ) . esc_html( $args['title'] ) . html_entity_decode( $args['after_title'] ) . "\n";          }
        $html .= '<div class="team-members component' . esc_attr( $class ) . '">' . "\n";

        // Begin templating logic.
        $tpl = '<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" class="%%CLASS%%">%%AVATAR%% %%TITLE%% <div id="team-member-%%ID%%"  class="team-member-text" itemprop="description">%%TEXT%% %%AUTHOR%%</div></div>';
        $tpl = apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_item_template', $tpl, $args );

        $count = 0;
        foreach ( $query as $post ) {
            $count++;
            $template = $tpl;

            $css_class = apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_class', $css_class = 'team-member' );
            if ( ( is_numeric( $args['per_row'] ) && ( 0 == ( $count - 1 ) % $args['per_row'] ) ) || 1 == $count ) { $css_class .= ' first'; }
            if ( ( is_numeric( $args['per_row'] ) && ( 0 == $count % $args['per_row'] ) ) ) { $css_class .= ' last'; }

            // Add a CSS class if no image is available.
            if ( isset( $post->image ) && ( '' == $post->image ) ) {
                $css_class .= ' no-image';
            }

            setup_postdata( $post );

            $title      = '';
            $title_name = '';

            // If we need to display the title, get the data
            if ( ( get_the_title( $post ) != '' ) && true == $args['display_author'] ) {
                $title .= '<h3 itemprop="name" class="member">';

                if ( true == $args['display_url'] && '' != $post->url && apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_url', true ) ) {
                    $title .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $post->url ) . '">' . "\n";
                }

                $title_name = get_the_title( $post );

                $title .= $title_name;

                if ( true == $args['display_url'] && '' != $post->url && apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_url', true ) ) {
                    $title .= '</a>' . "\n";
                }

                $title .= '</h3><!--/.member-->' . "\n";

                $member_role = '';

                if ( true == $args['display_role'] && isset( $post->byline ) && '' != $post->byline && apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_role', true ) ) {
                    $member_role .= ' <p class="role" itemprop="jobTitle">' . $post->byline . '</p><!--/.excerpt-->' . "\n";
                }

                $title .= apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_fields_display', $member_role );

            }

            // Templating engine replacement.
            $template       = str_replace( '%%TITLE%%', $title, $template );

            $author         = '';
            $author_text    = '';

            $user = $post->user_id;

            // If we need to display the author, get the data.
            if ( true == $args['display_additional'] ) {

                $author .= '<ul class="author-details">';

                $member_fields = '';

                if ( true == $args['display_author_archive'] && apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_user_id', true ) ) {

                    // User didn't select an item from the autocomplete list
                    // Let's try to get the user from the search query
                    if ( 0 == $post->user_id && '' != $post->user_search ) {
                        $user = get_user_by( 'slug', $post->user_search );
                        if ( $user ) {
                            $user = $user->ID;
                        }
                    }

                    if ( 0 != $user ) {
                        $member_fields .= '<li class="our-team-author-archive" itemprop="url"><a href="' . get_author_posts_url( $post->user_id ) . '">' . sprintf( __( 'Read posts by %1$s', 'our-team-by-woothemes' ), get_the_title() ) . '</a></li>' . "\n";
                    }

                }



                if ( true == $args['contact_email'] && '' != $post->contact_email && apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_contact_email', true ) ) {
                    $member_fields .= '<li class="our-team-contact-email" itemprop="email"><a href="mailto:' . esc_html( $post->contact_email ) . '">' . __( 'Email me ', 'our-team-by-woothemes' )  . '</a></li>';
                }





                if ( true == $args['tel'] && '' != $post->tel && apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_tel', true ) ) {
                    $call_protocol = apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_call_protocol', $protocol = 'tel' );
                    $member_fields .= '<li class="our-team-tel" itemprop="telephone"><span>' . __( 'Tel: ', 'our-team-by-woothemes' ) . '</span><a href="' . $call_protocol . ':' . esc_html( $post->tel ) . '">' . esc_html( $post->tel ) . '</a></li>';
                }



                if ( true == $args['display_twitter'] && '' != $post->twitter && apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_twitter', true ) ) {
                    $member_fields .= '<li class="our-team-twitter" itemprop="contactPoint"><a href="//twitter.com/' . esc_html( $post->twitter ) . '" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @' . esc_html( $post->twitter ) . '</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?"http":"https";if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");</script></li>'  . "\n";
                }

                $author .= apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_member_fields_display', $member_fields );

                $author .= '</ul>';

                // Templating engine replacement.
                $template = str_replace( '%%AUTHOR%%', $author, $template );
            } else {
                $template = str_replace( '%%AUTHOR%%', '', $template );
            }

            // Templating logic replacement.
            $template = str_replace( '%%ID%%', get_the_ID(), $template );
            $template = str_replace( '%%CLASS%%', esc_attr( $css_class ), $template );

            if ( isset( $post->image ) && ( '' != $post->image ) && true == $args['display_avatar'] ) {
                $template = str_replace( '%%AVATAR%%', '<figure itemprop="image">' . $post->image . '</figure>', $template );
            } else {
                $template = str_replace( '%%AVATAR%%', '', $template );
            }

            // Remove any remaining %%AVATAR%% template tags.
            $template   = str_replace( '%%AVATAR%%', '', $template );
            $real_more  = $more;
            $more       = 0;
            $content    = apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_content', wpautop( get_the_content( __( 'Read full biography...', 'our-team-by-woothemes' ) ) ), $post );
            $more       = $real_more;

            // Display bio if Team Member is mapped to a user on this site.
            if ( apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_display_bio', true ) && 0 != $user ) {
                if ( '' != get_the_author_meta( 'description', $user ) ) {
                    $content = wpautop( get_the_author_meta( 'description', $user ) );
                }
            }


            $template = str_replace( '%%TEXT%%', $content, $template );

            // filter the individual team member html
            $template = apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_html', $template, $post );

            // Assign for output.
            $html .= $template;
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

        if ( $args['pagination'] == true && count( $query ) > 1 && $args['effect'] != 'none' ) {
            $html .= '<div class="pagination">' . "\n";
            $html .= '<a href="#" class="btn-prev">' . apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_prev_btn', '&larr; ' . __( 'Previous', 'our-team-by-woothemes' ) ) . '</a>' . "\n";
            $html .= '<a href="#" class="btn-next">' . apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_next_btn', __( 'Next', 'our-team-by-woothemes' ) . ' &rarr;' ) . '</a>' . "\n";
            $html .= '</div><!--/.pagination-->' . "\n";
        }
        $html .= '</div><!--/.team-members-->' . "\n";
        $html .= $args['after'] . "\n";
    }

    // Allow child themes/plugins to filter here.
    $html = apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_html', $html, $query, $args );

    if ( $args['echo'] != true ) {
        return $html;
    }

    // Should only run is "echo" is set to true.
    echo $html;

    do_action( 'woothemes_our_team_after', $args ); // Only if "echo" is set to true.
} // End woothemes_our_team()
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woothemes_our_team_shortcode' ) ) {
/**
* The shortcode function.
* @since  1.0.0
* @param  array  $atts    Shortcode attributes.
* @param  string $content If the shortcode is a wrapper, this is the content being wrapped.
* @return string          Output using the template tag.
*/
function woothemes_our_team_shortcode ( $atts, $content = null ) {
$args = (array)$atts;

$defaults = array(
    'limit'                     => 12,
    'per_row'                   => null,
    'orderby'                   => 'menu_order',
    'order'                     => 'DESC',
    'id'                        => 0,
    'slug'                      => null,
    'display_author'            => true,
    'display_additional'        => true,
    'display_avatar'            => true,
    'display_url'               => true,
    'display_author_archive'    => true,
    'display_twitter'           => true,
    'display_role'              => true,
    'effect'                    => 'fade', // Options: 'fade', 'none'
    'pagination'                => false,
    'echo'                      => true,
    'size'                      => 250,
    'category'                  => 0,
    'title'                     => '',
    'before_title'              => '<h2>',
    'after_title'               => '</h2>'
);

$args = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts );

// Make sure we return and don't echo.
$args['echo'] = false;

// Fix integers.
if ( isset( $args['limit'] ) ) {
    $args['limit'] = intval( $args['limit'] );
}

if ( isset( $args['size'] ) &&  ( 0 < intval( $args['size'] ) ) ) {
    $args['size'] = intval( $args['size'] );
}

if ( isset( $args['category'] ) && is_numeric( $args['category'] ) ) {
    $args['category'] = intval( $args['category'] );
}

// Fix booleans.
foreach ( array( 'display_author', 'display_additional', 'display_url', 'display_author_archive', 'display_twitter', 'display_role', 'pagination', 'display_avatar' ) as $k => $v ) {
    if ( isset( $args[$v] ) && ( 'true' == $args[$v] ) ) {
        $args[$v] = true;
    } else {
        $args[$v] = false;
    }
}

return woothemes_our_team( $args );

} // End woothemes_our_team_shortcode()
}

add_shortcode( 'woothemes_our_team', 'woothemes_our_team_shortcode' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'woothemes_our_team_content_default_filters' ) ) {
/**
* Adds default filters to the "woothemes_our_team_content" filter point.
* @since  1.0.0
* @return void
*/
function woothemes_our_team_content_default_filters () {
add_filter( 'woothemes_our_team_content', 'do_shortcode' );
} // End woothemes_our_team_content_default_filters()

add_action( 'woothemes_our_team_before', 'woothemes_our_team_content_default_filters' );
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'woothemes_our_team_content' );
/**
* Display team member data on single / archive pages
* @since 1.4.0
* @return  $content the post content
*/
function woothemes_our_team_content( $content ) {
global $post;

$team_member_email  = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_gravatar_email', true ) );
$user               = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_user_id', true ) );
$user_search        = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_user_search', true ) );
$twitter            = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_twitter', true ) );
$role               = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_byline', true ) );
$url                = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_url', true ) );
$tel                = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_tel', true ) );
$contact_email      = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_contact_email', true ) );

if ( 'team-member' == get_post_type() ) {

    $team_member_gravatar   = '';
    $team_member_role       = '';
    $member_fields          = '';
    $author                 = '';

    if ( isset( $team_member_email ) && ( '' != $team_member_email ) ) {
        $team_member_gravatar = '<figure itemprop="image">' .  get_avatar( $team_member_email, 250 ) . '</figure>';
    }

    if ( isset( $role ) && '' != $role && apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_role', true ) ) {
        $team_member_role .= ' <p class="role" itemprop="jobTitle">' . $role . '</p>' . "\n";
    }

    $author .= '<ul class="author-details">';

    if ( apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_user_id', true ) ) {
        if ( 0 == $user && '' != $user_search ) {
            $user = get_user_by( 'slug', $user_search );
            if ( $user ) {
                $user = $user;
            }
        }

        if ( 0 != $user ) {
            $member_fields .= '<li class="our-team-author-archive" itemprop="url"><a href="' . get_author_posts_url( $user ) . '">' . sprintf( __( 'Read posts by %1$s', 'woothemes' ), get_the_title() ) . '</a></li>' . "\n";
        }
    }

    if ( '' != $tel && apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_contact_email', true ) ) {
        $member_fields .= '<li class="our-team-contact-email" itemprop="email"><a href="mailto:' . $contact_email . '">' . __( 'Email ', 'our-team-by-woothemes' ) . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    }

    if ( '' != $tel && apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_tel', true ) ) {
        $call_protocol = apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_call_protocol', $protocol = 'tel' );
        $member_fields .= '<li class="our-team-tel" itemprop="telephone"><span>' . __( 'Tel: ', 'our-team-by-woothemes' ) . '</span><a href="' . $call_protocol . ':' . $tel . '">' . $tel . '</a></li>';
    }

    if ( '' != $twitter && apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_team_member_twitter', true ) ) {
        $member_fields .= '<li class="our-team-twitter" itemprop="contactPoint"><a href="//twitter.com/' . esc_html( $twitter ) . '" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @' . esc_html( $twitter ) . '</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?"http":"https";if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");</script></li>'  . "\n";
    }

    $author .= apply_filters( 'woothemes_our_member_fields_display', $member_fields );

    $author .= '</ul>';

    return $team_member_gravatar . $team_member_role . $content . $author;
} else {
    return $content;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the template:

```
function so_27863277_our_team_template( $tpl, $args ){
    $tpl = '<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" class="%%CLASS%%">%%AVATAR%% %%TITLE%% <a href="#team-member-%%ID%%" class="lightbox">Read About Me</a><div id="team-member-%%ID%%"  class="team-member-text" itemprop="description">%%TEXT%% %%AUTHOR%%</div></div>';

    return $tpl;
}
add_filter( 'woothemes_our_team_item_template', 'so_27863277_our_team_template', 10, 2 );
```

Then by default, you might also want to style the `team-member-text` div so that it is hidden.

```
.team-member-text{ display: none; }
```

I'm not sure how to make it work with your particular lightbox plugin so you will have to adapt that part yourself.